# retrofitting a .h & .c file to my already working .c program

Tags: c, refactoring, header-files

I have a program that I'm doing for class where I need to take the content of one file, reverse it, and write that reversed content to another file. I have written a program that successfully does this (after much googling as I am new to the C programming language). The problem however is that my professor wants us to submit the program in a certain way with a couple supporting .h and .c files (which I understand is good practice). So I was hoping someone could help me understand exactly how I can take my already existing program and make it into one that is to his specifications, which are as follows:

- he would like a file named "file_utils.h" that has function signatures and guards for the following two functions

  int read_file( char* filename, char **buffer );

  int write_file( char* filename, char *buffer, int size);

thus far I have created this file to try and accomplish this.

```
#ifndef UTILS_H
#define UTILS_H

    int read_file(char* filename, char **buffer);
    int write_file(char* filename, char *buffer, int size);

#endif
```

- he would like a file named "file_utils.c" that has the implemented code for the previous two functions
- he would like a file named "reverse.c" that accepts command arguments, includes a main function, and calls the functions from the previous two files.

now. I understand how this is supposed to work, but as I'm looking at the program I wrote my way I'm unsure how to actually accomplish the same result by adhering to the previously mentioned specifications.

Below is the program that successfully accomplishes the desired functionality

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int file1, file2, char_count, x, k;
    char buffer;

    // if the number of parameters passed are not correct, exit
    //
    if (argc != 3) {
            fprintf(stderr, "usage %s <file1> <file2>", argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // if the origin file cannot be opened for whatever reason, exit
    // S_IRUSR specifies that this file is to be read by only the file owner
    //
    if ((file1 = open(argv[1], S_IRUSR)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "The origin-file is inaccessible");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // if the destination-file cannot be opened for whatever reason, exit
    // S_IWUSR specifies that this file is to be written to by only the file owner
    //
    if ((file2 = creat(argv[2], S_IWUSR)) < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "The destination-file is inaccessible");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    // SEEK_END is used to place the read/write pointer at the end of the file
    //
    char_count = lseek(file1, (off_t) 0, SEEK_END);
    printf("origin-file size is %d\n", char_count - 1);

    for (k = char_count - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            lseek(file1, (off_t) k, SEEK_SET);

            x = read(file1, &buffer, 1);

            if (x != 1) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "can't read 1 byte");
                    exit(-1);
            }

            x = write(file2, &buffer, 1);
            if (x != 1) {
                    fprintf(stderr, "can't write 1 byte");
                    exit(-1);

            }
    }
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, "Reversal & Transfer Complete\n", 5);
    close(file1);
    close(file2);

    return 0;
```

}

any insight as to how I can accomplish this "re-factoring" of sorts would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Start from scratch. It's really not that long to do so... moreover you can copy/paste relevant code. Do you know what these two functions are supposed to do?

Comment: @EugeneSh. there is no description for these two functions, only that we are supposed to use them and that together they are supposed to take the content of one file, reverse it, and write that to another file (just as the program at the bottom of the posting does).

Comment: Then take a look at their implementation. Chances that they are doing all of the file handling IO for you.

Comment: Oh, wait. I though.. the implementation is provided..

Answer (score 1):

The assignment demands a different architecture than your program. Unfortunately, this will not be a refactoring but a rewrite.

You have most of the pieces of `read_file` and `write_file` already: opening the file, determining its length, error handling. Those can be copy-pasted into the new functions.

But `read_file` should call `malloc` and read the file into memory, which is different.

You should create a new function in `reverse.c`, called by `main`, to reverse the bytes in a memory buffer.

After that function runs, `write_file` should attempt to open the file, and only do its error checking at that point.

Your simple program is superior because it validates the output file before any I/O, and it requires less memory. Its behavior satisfies the assignment, but its form does not.